# How to fix the positioning when rotating text nodes in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

% When I try to rotate nodes it jumps to the second page. How can I fix this?

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=61.1cm,paperwidth=61.1cm,margin=5mm}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfornament, tikzrput}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\centering
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\titlebox}[1]{%
\begin{center}
\begin{scope}
\node[align=center,draw,thick,text width=0.4\textwidth,inner sep=10mm, 
yshift=85mm] (titlebox)%
{\textsc{}\\[\baselineskip]\textbf{\huge #1}};\\
\node[fill=white] (W) at (titlebox.north) {\bfseries \Huge ISOAP};
\end{scope}
\end{center}
 }
\titlebox{\textsc{\Large{Rose Clear Hand Soap}}} % An example use
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=53.2cm, font=\fontsize{45pt} 
{45pt}\selectfont,
align=justify] at (0.4,-6) {%
{\textbf{INGREDIENTS:} }
};
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=53cm, font=\fontsize{45pt} 
{45pt}\selectfont, align=justify] at (0.4,-13) {%
{\textbf{CAUTION:} }
};
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=53cm, font=\fontsize{27pt} 
{27pt}\selectfont, align=center, rotate=90] at (-20,-25) {%
{{}MFG date: 10/10/19}
};
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=53cm, font=\fontsize{27pt} 
{27pt}\selectfont, align=center, rotate=90] at (-18,-25) {%
{{}EXP date: 10/2021}
 };
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=53cm, font=\fontsize{27pt} 
{27pt}\selectfont, align=center, rotate=-90] at (18,-24) {%
{{}Lot No 091091}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile because you have a `\\ ` in but the issues is that you rotate a node with `text width=53cm`, which is a bit too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the nodes that you rotate have an enormous text width, `text width=53cm`. If you rotate them, the vertical dimensions of the `tikzpicture` become too large, and the picture moves to the next page. If you fix it, the issue is gone.

```
\documentclass[20pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperheight=61.1cm,paperwidth=61.1cm,margin=5mm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{bookman}
\usepackage{pdfrender}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\centering
{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\titlebox}[1]{%
\begin{scope}
\node[align=center,draw,thick,text width=0.4\textwidth,inner sep=10mm, 
yshift=85mm] (titlebox)%
{\textsc{}\\[\baselineskip]\textbf{\huge #1}};
\node[fill=white] (W) at (titlebox.north) {\bfseries \Huge ISOAP};
\end{scope}}
\titlebox{\textsc{\Large{Rose Clear Hand Soap}}} % An example use
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=53.2cm, font=\fontsize{45pt} 
{45pt}\selectfont,
align=justify] at (0.4,-6) {%
{\textbf{INGREDIENTS:} }
};
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=53cm, font=\fontsize{45pt} 
{45pt}\selectfont, align=justify] at (0.4,-13) {%
{\textbf{CAUTION:} }
};
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=5cm, font=\fontsize{27pt} 
{27pt}\selectfont, align=center, rotate=90] at (-20,-25) {%
{{}MFG date: 10/10/19}
};
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=5cm, font=\fontsize{27pt} 
{27pt}\selectfont, align=center, rotate=90] at (-18,-25) {%
{{}EXP date: 10/2021}
 };
\node (example-textwidth-2) [text width=5cm, font=\fontsize{27pt} 
{27pt}\selectfont, align=center, rotate=-90] at (18,-24) {%
{{}Lot No 091091}
};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Please notice that in a `tikzpicture` the `center` environment does not have the effect it should have, and you had a `\\` which you should not have.